# Можно ли употреблять слово "опция" как синоним допвозможности?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

> Опция — факультативная, дополнительная возможность.

А не в наших (ли) силах расширить сферу употребления слова?

> В придачу к прекрасному виду на форум Траяна вы получите ещё несколько
>   приятных опций от одного из модных в прошлом ресторанов, в котором
>   старые официанты всё ещё дуются от важности.

Закавычить чи шо?

Comment: Замените на "несколько привлекательных / заманчивых предложений"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На компьютерном языке "опция" — не факультативная, дополнительная возможность, а просто "возможность", "параметр" или даже "режим работы", как подсказывает словарь Кузнецова (и это правильно).

А сфера употребления слова уже и так расширена до невозможности. Подобные фразы мелькают тут и там, так что, думаю, вполне нормально будет.

Comment: Кавычим ли? Пока не утрамбуется?

Comment: Нееет... Уже утрамбовалось. Сколько видел, нигде не кавычат.

Comment: Интересно, как это "возможность" может быть ***не факультативной***?

Comment: Да так... Бывает просто возможность, а бывает дополнительная возможность. Или, что почти то же самое, "факультативная", хотя лично мне это слово здесь и не нравится.

Comment: В чем разница-то? Возможность она всегда факультативна.

Comment: Кавычить не надо. Надо бы заменить на синоним. Это слово уместно в разговоре или переписке между туроператорами, но в тексте рекламы неприятно раздражает.

Answer (score 2):

> Закавычить

От целевой аудитории сильно зависит. Здесь я бы закавычивал.
Тут вот какая штука. "Опция" стало до некоторой степени привычно за пределами профжаргона только в одном значении: "то, чем можно воспользоваться по выбору (обычно даже - из нескольких альтернативных вариантов)". А у официантов какая такая опция? Без контекста и непонятно.

То, что там Niemand чего-то не видел - не показатель. Во-первых, ничего не доказывает, а во-вторых, в подобном контексте это нечто непонятное.

Хотя, с другой стороны, подобные рекламные тексты явно не располагают к обилию знаков препинания... Так что можно и оставить.

Насчет непонятности и факультативности.

> ФАКУЛЬТАТИВНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -вен, -вна, -вно. [франц. facultatif] 1.
>   Необязательный, нерегулярный. Ф-ые явления. Ф-ые нормы
>   (ориентировочные). Ф-ые скобки (заключающие ту часть слова или
>   предложения, которую можно пропустить). 2. Служащий для дополнительной
>   специализации, выбираемый по желанию (обычно учебный курс в высшем
>   учебном заведении или старших классах школы). Ф. курс лекций. Ф-ые
>   занятия. Ф. семинар. <Факультативно, нареч. Изучать что-л. ф.

Возможность она всегда "факультативна" и "дополнительна" по своему смыслу.  Если, конечно, автор сознательно не вкладывает, какой-то свой смысл. Непонятность же возникает по причине использования в данном контексте. Тут проблема в другом. "Опции от ресторана", скорее всего, вставлено для красного словца. Ибо никакие это не опции, а обычные предложения от ресторана. Опция могла бы быть, скажем, при комплексном обеде - дополнительные десерт, например. ))) Вряд ли что-то подобное можно ожидать от заведения с видом на форум Траяна.

Comment: Г-н Мимоходов, вы же айтишник... Как это вам непонятна "опция" в каком угодно контексте?!

Comment: @Niemand, см. мой профиль.

Comment: *Niemand, см. мой профиль.*  Г-н @Мимоходов, вы же как есть айтишник.

Comment: @Niemand, см. мой профиль

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что **кавычки не нужны**. Прямое значение слово достаточно известно,  а в данном тексте оно выглядит как авторская  **метафора.**

Answer (score 1):

Воспринимается плохо. Мысль выражена туманно и то ли напыщенно, то ли в дословном переводе с английского. Если поставить кавычки - станет еще непонятней, будет создаваться впечатление, что опции ненастоящие или автор имел в виду что-то особенное, обозначаемое этим словом. Впрочем, кто его знает, что он имел в виду...